# Non-square TerrainQuad

Tags: java, game-engine, terrain, jmonkeyengine

I am trying to create a game in which there is a tabletop that users can manipulate: they can change the height of vertices to create hills.

I am using JME3 (JMonkeyEngine) for this.

I am trying to use TerrainQuad [see here](http://javadoc.jmonkeyengine.org/com/jme3/terrain/geomipmap/TerrainQuad.html).
Because of certain restrictions on the editing of the terrain, I need my tabletop to be 20x20 quads.
According to the specification of TerrainQuad, I can only have a size of 2^N +1.
Can I still use TerrainQuad? If so, how?